# Regular expression to match dot which has letter after it, before next dot or end of line

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which will match a dot `.` which has a letter after it at some point before the next dot `.` or end of line.

For example the following would be valid: `.foo.bar`.

`.foo.123` would be invalid because it contains `.123` which has no letters after the dot.

So far I've got:

```
^([a-z0-9)]|\.(?=.*[a-z].*\.))+$
```

I understand that the problem with the above is the final match for a `.` in the positive lookahead: it will always fail to match. I think something like "if dot exists match, else match end of line". If I use `($|\.)` in place of the final match this still doesn't work, I assume because it tries both even when a `.` is matched.

I'd like to avoid using look-behinds. I want match the whole string, not just the dots.

Comment: Do you want to mention just the `.` or the entire line?

Comment: In `.foo.123`, shouldn't the part `.foo.` match as it has a dot followed by "letters" followed by another dot? Give some more examples/test cases to clarify.

Comment: Do you want to match the individual dots or validate a complete string as matching or not?

Comment: @AlexCollins The entire line.

Comment: @trincot I want to validate a complete string.

Comment: What is allowed to appear before the first dot, if anything?

Comment: What about [`^(\.[^.]*[a-z][^.]*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/znbS58/1) ?

Comment: @trincot No characters before the first dot. But this is a minimal example for a much bigger expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex possibly with some small changes should work. `^(?:\.[^\.\s]*[a-zA-Z][^\.\s]*)+$`

Regex101 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFzGtt/4).

Breakdown of how it works:

- `^` - Start of new line
- `(?:\.[^\.\s]*[a-zA-Z][^\.\s]*)` - Grab period followed by all text before the next period or new line. Ensure there is at least one letter.

  - `\.` - Start with period.
  - `[^\.\s]*` - Anything but a space or `.` any number of times.
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - Ensure at least one letter per period.
  - `[^\.\s]*` - Anything but a space or `.` any number of times.
- `+` - Once or more
- `$` - End of line

Comment: This works great. Could you clarify what you mean by "Since this is a repeated group there may be periods at the start as long as they are followed by letters".

Comment: Seems the ? mark is actually a copy error from an earlier regex which it was needed. It should just match a period not an optional period. This mistake  broke the case `Letters.foo`. This is why test cases are important!

Comment: Updated with the `?` mark removed and a more clear description.